# Update parent components from child component in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have the main Component using the Parent component having a dynamic component using the  *v-bind:is*="**componentName**" just like:

**Parent template:**

```
<li class='list-inline-item g-mx-4 g-mt-10'>
  <component v-bind:is="componentName"></component>
</li>
```

and code:

```
 export default {

    data: function(){
             return  {
               componentName : "componentA"
             },
     },
    components: {
        componentA: {
            template : "<div>A</div>" 
        },
        componentB: {
          template : "  <div>B</div>"
        }
     }
```

I would like to switch the component to show sending a new value to **componentName** from a child component but I'm not sure if I have to use emit or watch or...?

I would like to do that without vuex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, use emit.
In your parent component do something like :

```
<child-component @custom_event='methodName' />
```

And in a method of the child component :

```
this.$emit('custom_event')
```

Comment: Thanks Loïc! I have update my script using emit and it works very well! Simple but very helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I got solved it using [emit](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-custom-events.html) as Loric suggested.

My new parent component is now:

```
   <li class='list-inline-item g-mx-4 g-mt-10'>
       <component v-bind:is="componentName"  @custom_event='updateTest'></component>
   </li>
```

and  it has a mtehod like:

```
 methods: {
        updateTest() {
            const v = document.querySelector('meta[name="login-status"]').getAttribute("content");
            this.componentName =  (v!="") ? "componentLoggedOn" : "componentLoggedOff";
        },
    },
```

then I have add a new method to componentA component ( the one created inline) having:

> this.$emit('custom_event', *param*);

Note: *param* is not used but just in case...

Comment: note that you can replace "custom_event" name with anything.
For instance I have a component that is an ajax form, and it emits "submit" and "response".
Also if you use `v-bind` you should use `v-on` to be consistent :
Either : `v-bind:is="componentName"  v-on:custom_event='updateTest'`
or the short version : `:is="componentName"  @custom_event='updateTest'`

Comment: Also more globally you are missing something big about vuejs.
You shouldn't check the status of someone logged in like that.
login_status could be a variable in your child-component, which is not optimal. It could also be a variable in vue-x.
Or it could even be a global variable of your view instance.

Comment: Thanks @Loïc. I agree with you. I'm new on vue and I'm working on a blueprint project. I'll introduce Vuex in my project very soon.